# One Hot Encoding a composite field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, one-hot-encoding, multivalue

I want to transform multiple columns with same categorical values using a `OneHotEncoder`. I created a composite field and tried to use `OneHotEncoder` on it as below: (Items 1-3 are from the same list of items)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("basket", myConcat("item1", "item2", "item3")) 
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="basket", outputCol="basketIndex")
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(setInputCol="basketIndex", setOutputCol="basketVec")

encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)

def myConcat(*cols):
    return F.concat(*[F.coalesce(c, F.lit("*")) for c in cols])
```

I am getting an *out of memory error*.

Does this approach work? How do I one hot encode a composite field or multiple columns with categorical values from same list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have categorical values array why you didn't try CountVectorizer:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer

df = df.withColumn("basket", myConcat("item1", "item2", "item3")) 
indexer = CountVectorizer(inputCol="basket", outputCol="basketIndex")
indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about CountVectorizer. Will try soon and post the results here.

Comment: CountVectorizer worked! Thanks. I had to use the F.array instead of myConcat:
```df = df.withColumn("basket", F.array("item1", "item2", "item3"))```
Now, OneHotEncoder is throwing:

_Input column must be of type NumericType but got org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector_

Is there a way to OneHotEncode a vector. Sorry, I haven't read the manual yet. Thanks for your time!

Comment: After countvectorizer is used, i think there is no need to onehotencoding. They both generates vector.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I can't comment yet (due to the fact that I'm a new user).

What is the cardinality of your "item1", "item2" and "item3"

More specifically, what are the values that the following prints is giving ?

```
k1 = df.item1.nunique()
k2 = df.item2.nunique()
k3 = df.item3.nunique()
k = k1 * k2 * k3
print (k1, k2, k3)
```

One hot encoding is basically creating a very sparse matrix of same number of rows as your original dataframe with k number of additional columns, where k = products of the three numbers printed above.

Therefore, if your 3 numbers are large, you get out of memory error.

The only solutions are to:

(1) increase your memory or
(2) introduce a hierarchy among the categories and use the higher level categories to limit k.

Comment: Thanks. k1 = k2 = k3 which is approximately 2000 and the number of records is about 250,000. I increased the memory, but did not work. But, I am not confident about my approach.